# How to configure php.ini file for mail() in MAC OS?

Tags: sendmail, php

I'm using MAC OS and using mail() to send the student details to my mail.

It does not shows any errors, but the details are not sent to mail.

Is there any setup in php.ini for SMTP settings?

Answer (score 11):

For OSX Yosemite, this fixed me right up:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
SMTP=localhost
smtp_port=25
sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Ensure that you have your `postfix` configured - check out this link to learn more: http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 3):

1. 

```
sudo nano -w /etc/hostconfig

MAILSERVER=-YES-
```

2. 

```
sudo cp /etc/postfix/main.cf /etc/postfix/main.cf.org
sudo nano -w /etc/postfix/main.cf

myhostname=my.known.host
```

3. 

```
# php.ini
sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i"
```

Source: http://theandystratton.com/2009/fix-phps-mail-function-after-latest-os-x-leopard-update

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the OS X Server app from the App Store. I believe it's free, at least for developers. If you turn on the Mail option, it sets up postfix for you. You'll need a relay or you'll need your computer to have an established domain; sending e-mail is easy, but not having it rejected is hard :D

Comment: It is $30, still worth it!